# Create readable pdf from binary pdf file using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, utf-8, binary

I have a file named DATA.TXT(also contains image in form of binary) which contains data in binary form.Its type is application/pdf and charset=binary.Then, want to convert this into readable pdf.How to convert using ruby.I tried converting it into utf-8 encoding but there are multiple special characters which does not allow reading it using PDF Reader gem and throws error of Malformed.I have also tried converting binary to base64 and then decode it.Also, tried with chilkat library.Also, I tried renaming the file extension to .pdf and open in adobe pdf reader.It says failed to load document.
Do let me know me your suggestions , it would be of great help!

Comment: The file is DATA.txt and it has content like this: 2550 4446 2d31 2e37 0a25 c7ec 8fa2 0a35 2030 206f 626a 0a3c 3c2f 4c65 6e67 7468.And, when I convert it to utf-8 encoding then I see %PDF-1.7....with special charaters and some text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reformat your question text to make it more readable, and include some code examples to illustrate what you have tried so far.